# getElementById() in an Array() is overwriting other elements in the array

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, multidimensional-array, getelementbyid

I feel like this should have a really simple answer, but I'm still scratching my head and Google isn't helping. I'm trying to store information about an element in an array. However in Google Chrome, when I set information about the second element, it overwrites the first. Here's the simplified version of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var $box = new Array();
      $box['test'] = new Array();
      function load(){
        $box['test'][document.getElementById('box')] = true;
        $box['test'][document.getElementById('boxinfo')] = false;

        console.log('box: ' + $box['test'][document.getElementById('box')]);                // box: false      // Should be true
        console.log('boxinfo: ' + $box['test'][document.getElementById('boxinfo')]);        // boxinfo: false  // Should be false
        console.log(document.getElementById('box') == document.getElementById('boxinfo'));  // false           // Should be false
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load();">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="boxinfo">BoxInfo</div>
      Box
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make it so that

```
$box['test'][document.getElementById('box')]          // is true
$box['test'][document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]] // is true
$box['test'][document.getElementById('boxinfo')]      // is false
```

Comment: Btw, on arrays, don't create named properties; use indexes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing

```
foo[ bar ] = someValue;
```

`bar` is converted into a *String* value, which is then used as the property name (which is being assigned to). In your case, your DOM elements are converted into strings like `'[object HTMLDivElement]'`. If both your elements are DIVs, they will be converted into the same *String* value, which is why the second assignment overwrites the first one, i.e. both assignments assign to the same property.

What you're trying to achieve, cannot be implemented with a simple array.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So is there any way to convert each element into a unique string, so that `$box['test'][document.getElementById('box')]` and `$box['test'][document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]]` are the same value and `$box['test'][document.getElementById('boxinfo')]` is different. I know doing `$box['test'][document.getElementById('box').outerHTML]` will work, but is there anything more efficient?

Comment: @SuperKingT `.outerHTML`, i.e. serializing the DOM for the purpose of generating an unique string would be an awful solution (and also, the string would *not* be guaranteedly unique). Consider having a custom function which converts DOM references to unique string, e.g. `$box.test[ refToStr(document.getElementById('box')) ]`.

Comment: @SuperKingT Also consider implementing a more high level API, e.g. `coll.addElem( box, true )` and `coll.getValue( box ) // returns true`.

Comment: **IF** all browsers supported prototype inheritance, you might do something like `HTMLElement.prototype.toString = function(){return this.id)}`, but that would be frowned upon for assuming support for non-standard features, modifying host objects and requiring functionality known to be missing in a good number of browsers. But it is appealing. And some browsers actively prevent modification of host objects.